# When we call a api with post request it's showing [Error: Network Error]

Tags: react-native, axios

Showing network error when i call the post api in react native and i am using axios.

Here is my code

```
export const walletRequest = async () => {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      userID: 'BLOCALEVIG',
      password: 'bloc@!2@22ev!g',
      'Content-type': 'Application/json',
      Accept: 'Application/json',
    },
  };

  let data = {
    mfsapiin: {
      ReqService: 'WAL_API_WALLETSCREEN',
      mobileNumber: '8639833477',
    },
  };

  let url = `https://app.blocal.co.in:5959/mfmbs/mbintf/ina/processwalletapirequest.jsp?mfsapiin={
      "ReqService":"WAL_API_WALLETSCREEN",
      "mobileNumber":"8639833477"
      }`;

  const walletCheck = await axios
    .post(url, data, config)
    .then(resp => console.log('walletRequest.resp', resp))
    .catch(error => console.log('walletRequest.err', error));
  console.log('walletCheck', walletCheck);
};
```

[image]

Kindly tell me what is wrong in my code

Comment: in the right of your screen there is a bracket icon, press it and it's going to give you a code with a dropdown list select javascript fetch, copy the code and use it in your app as simple as that

Comment: and in your case you probably have a problem in data structure, the data required is a json raw